# Как вывести несколько тегов <meta> из массива?

Tags: reactjs, map, nextjs, meta

Необходимо вывести несколько одинаковых по смыслу  тегов с содержимым из массива:

```
const meta = {
  originTrials: ['first', 'second'],
};
```

В JSX реализовал это так:

```
{meta.originTrials.flatMap((originTrial, index) => (
   <meta key={index} httpEquiv="origin-trial" content={originTrial} />
))}
```

По итогу выведен лишь один мета с последним элементов массива.

```
<meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="second">
```

Так же пробовал вынести код приведенный выше в отдельный компонент, который обернул фрагментом (<> ... </>) и при обновлении страницы все теги вывелись, но после полной её загрузки вообще исчезли. Что я делаю не так?

Весь код примерно выглядит так:

```
import Head from 'next/head';

type Props = {
  pageTitle: string;
};

const meta = {
  originTrials: ['first', 'second'],
};

const Meta: React.FC<Props> = ({ pageTitle }: Props) => {
  return (
    <Head>
      {/* ... */}

      <title>{pageTitle}</title>

      {meta.originTrials.map((originTrial, index) => (
        <meta
          key={index}
          httpEquiv="origin-trial"
          content={originTrial}
        />
      ))}

      {/* ... */}
    </Head>
  );
};

export default Meta;
```

Comment: `map` вместо `flatMap`, не понял зачем он там

Comment: Согласен, только это ситуацию не меняет в данном случае, та же самая проблема

Comment: такого быть не может, цикл составлен правильно. Ищи проблему в другом месте.

Comment: А может ли "срезать" эти теги сам Next.js?

Comment: ну вы лучше целый кусок кода покажите, а то так тяжело сказать

Comment: Выложил код в вопросе

Comment: а, ну так они оверайдятся. А вы знаете зачем эти мета тэги?

Comment: Да, но конкретно этот тег тут лишь для примера. Т.е. без их перезаписи в таком случае вообще никак не выйдет?